# Are FAA aviation chart expiration dates inclusive or exclusive?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules, aeronautical-charts

If an aviation chart like a sectional or approach plate says it expires on July 14th, does it expire at 0001 midnight at the beginning of July 14th, or does it expire at 2359 at the end of the the day? I Searched Garmin website and did some searching and research on FAA website but couldn't find answer. If anyone has a source that would be awesome.